# iPhone:How to display data in Tableview only one time?

Tags: iphone

I am successfully display data in Tableview but next time I want not loading Tableview to display data so in short only one time Tableview loaded and after that its not loaded so please tell me any link or any idea to develop this functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can successully load data from data source, you must be aware emptying it or not calling reloadData will not reload the tableview.

Comment: Sorry but I have trouble to understand you needs, could you please be more specific ? I understood you want to load data once into a TableView and then keep information, but what do you call "next time" ? 

Thanks

Comment: Did not get the question properly

Comment: TableView load with data only one time

Comment: Please rephrase your question. I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

After displaying your data in the TableView, set a flag that `dataDispalyed = YES`.
Use a `if condition` in the TableView delegate method to check whether you have displayed your data.